# Circuit works with one phototransistor but not with another

Tags: uart, serial, infrared, phototransistor

I created a circuit board with an [SFH 309 FA](https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-5452331/SFH%20309%20FA_EN.pdf) phototransistor that works as an IR receiver for a serial data stream of a smart meter (this works without any problems).

Now I've changed the circuit to use only SMT components and went for a [PT26-21B/TR8](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/143/Everlight_06092016_PT26-21B-1165986.pdf) as a SMT replacement for the SFH 309.

But now the serial data that comes in is just crap.

I use a [74LVC1G17DBVR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g17.pdf) Schmitt trigger to improve the signal in both versions so I guess that's not the problem.

Here's the schematic:

[image]

I don't understand phototransistors well enough to see which parameter is the problem here and I hope somebody can give me a hint on how to fix the problem, or even better, which SMT phototransistor could be a working replacement for the SFH 309.

**Edit1:**

Here are two measurements done with an old scope I have at hand between R1 and Q1:

Working PCB with SFH 309:

[image]

Not woking with PT26:

[image]

Even the signal of the working one is far from good but it works.

**Edit2:**

As suggested by @JohnBrickhead I changed the circuit to use a comperator rather than a Schmitt Trigger.

[image]

After I've received the PCBs I'll let you know if this was the solution :-)

**Edit3**:

Stupid me accidentally interchanged the + and - of the comperator which led to an inversed UART signal. But it also turned out that R1 at 1k didn't work because the sinal never fully went to GND. after a quick test with a 10k it looked ok.

So after another round of waiting for the next PCB order the correct boards arrived and they work like charm :-)

I decided not to populate the feedback resistor which seems ok.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the signal that comes back?  Could you post perhaps the good and bad oscilloscope traces?  Is there any possibility it's a brightness issue -- have you tried test with IR LED?

Comment: what's the frequency of the emitted signal ?

Comment: Have you tried changing R1=10 k? I should use 1k (to be checked).

Comment: Bias point probably changed . Try varying resistor value. Also try a slightly translucent window. Also an IR transparent window - maybe deep red. A DMM should be able to measure the Q1/R1 junction DC voltage.

Comment: @jonathanjo I'm not able to change the TX side as it is in the smart meter. With an IR led I see that the input goes from low to high and vice versa but thats totally expected.
Rahmany its a 9600Baud serial protocol, so quite slow
Antonio51 RussellMcMahon no but I think I'll use a poteniometer to see how the R1 value affects the signal

Comment: Don't short your pot. A minimum is to be used ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is rise time.  When your Phototransistor turns "on" you are actively pulling down R1 with a low impedance, giving you a nice edge.  But when the transistor turns off, you are pulling up the signal with 10K, so the capacitance causes an exponential-looking signal on your rising edge.  The output of your Schmitt Trigger device doesn't change states until your rising signal hits 2 volts, so your positive pulses are too skinny.

It will probably help to decrease the value of R1 and give you a faster rise time, but the best approach might be to use a comparator instead of a Schmitt trigger, and set the threshold at a low voltage - maybe 250 mV or so.  You can put a little hysteresis in the comparator circuit.

Comment: Do I need to look for some kind of specific comperator? Does a [LMV321IDBVR](https://www.ti.com/cn/lit/ds/symlink/lmv321.pdf) work in this case? Thats available in a nice SOT-23-5 case at JLCPCB :-)

Comment: First, I would make sure you don't have a capacitor on U3 Pin 2.  Then I would use a comparator rather than an op amp.  Just make sure it has rail-to-rail inputs.

Comment: Then I would use a comparator rather than an op amp.  Just make sure it has rail-to-rail inputs.  An op amp operated open-loop can have unpredictable results for rise times.  Make sure your comparator has a push-pull output, not an open drain.  You can drive U3 directly with the comparator instead of the FET.

Comment: Ok, so I could go for the [MCP6541T-I/OT](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP6541OutputSubMicroampComparators20001696K.pdf), its a comperator, has apush-pull output and is in stock at JLCPCB. Is there a need for a Schmitt Trigger after the comperator or can I simply connect the output to my UART receiver pin?

Comment: Sure but you don't need a Schmitt Trigger - just add some hysteresis to the comparator.  There are plenty of app notes for comparators showing how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Decreasing the value of R1 will definitely help as John Birckhead pointed out. Maybe 4k7 or 2k2 could be enough to get it working again.

If that is not an option (limited power available, I mean if 0.5mA do really matter) there are other possibilities.

You may look for another SMD phototransistor that has a more detailed datasheet and where specification in terms of rise time, fall time, capacitance match better with SFH309. The SFH309 could reach 7µs with R1 being only 1k. In contrast the data sheet of the PT26 says "it's fast" but gives not any quantity for it's speed telling me it might be slow ;)

Take also care for the photo current Ipce per Ee ratio. Ee here tells how much light there is, and how much Ipce it generates. You should also look for an phototransistor giving the same or more current at the given Ee value (better said, should have the same or bigger ratio between Ipce/Ee).